# Утечка памяти при использовании QProcess и SSH

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, утечка-памяти

Пишу ПО под Linux которое подключается к аналогичным машинам и выполняет простенькие команды а-ля `cat /proc/meminfo` и подобные выводящие инфу о состоянии ОС.

При длительной работе моего ПО на стороне подконтрольных машин возникает постепенное увеличение потребления ОЗУ. Методом включения и выключения моего ПО и замеров потребления ОЗУ средствами гипервизора выяснил, что виновником служит именно мое ПО.

Странно то, что утечка памяти происходит именно на других машинах. Поэтому киваю больше на участок кода, который отвечает за подключение по SSH. В связи с этим правильно ли написан код делающий запрос по SSH? Пример запроса ниже

```
qDebug() << "GetARMStatus " << ip;
m->lock();
int result = 0;
QString command = "ssh";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "user@" + ip << " ps aux | grep openvpn; ";

QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
myProcess->start(command, arguments);
myProcess->waitForFinished();
myProcess->kill();

QString out = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();
QString err = myProcess->readAllStandardError();

if((err.contains("No route to host")) || (out.contains("No route to host"))) {
    result = 1;
}

if(out.contains("openvpn --daemon ovpn-client --status")) {
    result = 0;
} else {
    result = 1;
}

qDebug() << "GetARMStatus " << result << " " << ip;
delete myProcess;
m->unlock();
return result;
```

Comment: с виду всё нормально... только зачем QProcess в куче? если внутри кто-то исключение бросает, то он, конечно, будет утекать, но Qt ЕМНИП этим не особо балуется и это достаточно заметно...  По поводу проблемы — расчехляй `valgrind` и ищи утечку...

Answer (score 0):

1) наследовать указатели от родителя

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
```

2) использовать умные указатели

```
QSharedPointer<QProcess> p = QSharedPointer<QProcess>(new QProcess);
```

3) не использовать указатели там где они не нужны